# Binding combobox to a propery of enum type does not fire set accessor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, binding

## Setup

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyEnum _val;
    public MyEnum Val 
    {
         get { return _val; }
         set { _val = value; }
    }
}
```

and the following enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  EnumValue1 = 0,
  ...
  EnumValue5 = 4
}
```

I also have a WinForms ComboBox

## Desired behavior

I want to fill the combobox with values from MyEnum and bind the combobox's selected index to the MyClass.Val property and have the combobox update this property whenever I change the selection in the combobox.

## Problem

For some reason the combobox does not invoke the set accessor of my property when I change the value of the combobox, BUT the get accessor *is* invoked without any problems or exceptions

I do my bindings as follows:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();

ComboBox cb = c //I get the c value by iterating through my WebForms Form's Controls collection

cb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)); //This populates the values of the combobox and works OK
cb.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", mc, "Val", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); //This seems to partially work: only the get accessor is called, the set accessor is never called
```

I've read many other similar threads, but they were either irrelevant (suggesting to use DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged or were related to WPF) or did not help (suggesting to convert the enum to List prior to binding it).

## Question

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Can anyone advise on how to make the combobox call the set accessor?

Comment: At what point in your code are you setting the value of MyClass.Val?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, you should set [Binding.FormattingEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` and bind to [SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this

```
cb.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", mc, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

`SelectedValue` is a logical choice because it's the same type as the target property (`MyEnum` in this case), while `SelectedIndex` is `int` type and requires conversion.

If you are interested why binding to `SelectedIndex` works only in one direction and not in the other, here is an explanation:

```
// Updating control from data source
var v1 = Convert.ChangeType(MyEnum.EnumValue1, typeof(int)); // Ok, v1 = 0
// Updating data source from control
var v2 = Convert.ChangeType(0, typeof(MyEnum)); // InvalidCastException
```

The exception is hidden from you by data binding infrastructure. You can see it if you attach a handler to the [Binding.BindingComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.bindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: Ivan, thank you for your brilliant explanation. Changing the binding as per your recommendation solved the problem.

Comment: A small update: I had to do the following after binding the combobox: cb.SelectedIndex = (int)mc.Val, without it the combobox did not show the currently selected value, though Binding.BindingComplete did not have any errors and the get accessor got invoked properly. Weird.